# Stream Closed Error Groovy

Tags: file, groovy, ftp, md5, message-digest

Hi I am trying to connect FTP and read a file and generate md5 checksum value for that file, but I am facing Stream Closed error. Here is my code.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

FTPClient ftp=new FTPClient();
ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
ftp.connect("address");
ftp.login('username','password');
InputStream iStream=ftp.retrieveFileStream("path of the file");
BufferedInputStream bInf=new BufferedInputStream(iStream);
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];    
int read = 0;
while ((read = bInf.read(buffer)) !=-1)
{
digest.update(buffer, 0, read);
};

byte[] md5sum = digest.digest();
BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(1, md5sum)
def x=bigInt.toString(16).padLeft(32,'0')
```

Kindly help me where I went wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work with the following code:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient

MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")

String md5 = new FTPClient().with { ftp ->
    try {
        ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode()
        ftp.connect( address )
        ftp.login( username, password )
        ftp.retrieveFileStream( path ).with { ins ->
            if( ins == null ) {
                println "ERROR: $ftp.replyCode '${ftp.replyString.trim()}'"
            }
            else {
                try {
                    ins.eachByte( 8192 ) { buffer, nbytes ->
                        digest.update( buffer, 0, nbytes )
                    }
                    digest.digest().encodeHex().toString().padLeft( 32, '0' )
                }
                finally {
                    ins.close()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    finally {
        ftp.disconnect()
    }
}
```

(assuming you have variables defined for `address`, `username`, `password` and `path`)

Comment: It says Cannot invoke method close() on null object. It is going at  eachByte( 8192 ) { buffer, nbytes ->
                    digest.update( buffer, 0, nbytes )

Comment: Don't understand the second part of you comment...  Anyway, try that, I was more explicit with my `with` variable names.  What version of Groovy?  I tested that with `2.2.2` and `commons-net:commons-net:3.3` for `FTPClient`, and it works for me...

Comment: Actually retrieveFileStream is returning null

Comment: Maybe check the path exists?

Comment: yes the path exists It is throwing error Cannot invoke method close() on null object.

Comment: Is it a path to a valid object or is it a symbolic link? I know it's a  dreadful response, but yet again _"it works on my machine"_

Comment: :when I try to print digest.update( buffer, 0, nbytes ) .It prints value as null

Comment: Yes, because it didn't get an inputStream so wrote no bytes into the digest and crashed tying to close a null inputStream. As it says in [the documentation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#retrieveFileStream(java.lang.String)) _"Returns:
An InputStream from which the remote file can be read. If the data connection cannot be opened (e.g., the file does not exist), null is returned (in which case you may check the reply code to determine the exact reason for failure)."_

Comment: @ShashankCool Updated answer to catch null input stream and print the reply which should show why it was null

Comment: Could you please help me how to check the replycode in this program @tim_yates

Comment: @ShashankCool I have.  See the answer

Comment: It is printing RROR: 200 '200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.' @tim_yates

Comment: What happens if you remove `ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode()`?

Comment: Your Code is correct but it is not working in my case @tim_yates

Comment: @ShashankCool [this seems to suggest](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/java-ftp-file-download-tutorial-and-example#SampleCode) you need a call to `completePendingCommand` but I'm struggling to get it to work with my code...

Comment: Thank you for the help @tim_yates . Even I am unable to find the issue yet . It is throwing the same error Cannot invoke method close() on null object